# EJB3 Container Managed Persistence - When does an entity become unmanaged

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, ejb-3.0, jta

With container-managed JPA persistence, container-managed JTA transactions, and an entity manager injected into stateless local session beans, what does invoking a transaction-not-supported method do to the managed state of an entity?   I have read this: https://community.jboss.org/thread/183007 and similar threads, but there seems to be some ambiguity around whether a PC gets propagated to a NOT_SUPPORTED method if they both use injected EMs from the same factory?

Consider this snippet from a a bean that is going to retrieve an item and then invoke a method from another bean:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@Inject
private LeanBean leanBean;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void startHere() {
   MyItem item = em.find(MyItem.class, key);  
   leanBean.txMethod(item);
   leanBean.nonTxMethod(item);
}
```

Now here is LeanBean.java. Note that its two methods have different transaction propagation

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public Class LeanBean {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
   public void txMethod(MyItem item) {
      doSomething(item); // item is managed; persistence context propagated with 
   }                     // transaction context; em is the same as my caller's em

   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
   public void nonTxMethod(MyItem item) {
      doSomething(item); // caller's transaction context has been suspsended.
   }                     // did em propagate?  is item managed?

}
```

What I can't figure out from the spec(s):

1. Inside nonTxMethod, is item in a detached state?  What is supposed to happen if I reference em?
2. What if the method in the calling snippet had been annotated TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED?  would would be the state of item in either of the methods inside LeanBean?

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to keep an entity attached inside a method that I do not want to have as part of a transaction.

Comment: More specifically, if, inside nonTxMethod, I tried to access a lazily fetched field of MyItem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Inside nonTxMethod, is item in a detached state? What is supposed to
>   happen if I reference em?

TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED is just a way to  tell that your method does not need transaction and you will not be able call persist, merge or remove in EntityManager. But you can still call other methods like `em.find(Someclass.class,objectId)` . So i think the entity is not in a detached state .

> What if the method in the calling snippet had been annotated
>   TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED? would would be the state of
>   item in either of the methods inside LeanBean?

This will work exactly the same as previous. Just make sure that , whenever you will put `TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED` in your calling method eg `startHere()`, all the subsequent method calls transaction state would be suspended , and if you need trasaction in any of the subsequent calls you have to explicitely specify `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED` above that method .

And by default when you call any session bean's method from outside of the EJB , let from the JSP , the trasaction will automatically started unless you specify explicitly that you don't need transaction.